# Peak detect and hold in Labview

Tags: labview

I've inherited a labview "circuit" that integrates G's to output IPS. The problem is, the output text window (double), at full speed, has numbers scrolling so fast, you can't read them. I only need to see the largest number detected. I'm not too well versed in LabView - Can anyone help me through a function that will display the largest number outputted to the text window for a duration of 1/2 second? I'm basically looking for a peak detect-and-hold function... I'd prefer to work with the double precision value that is constantly updated if possible, rather than the array feeding my integrator. I tried looking through the Functions>signal processing menu, saw one peak detector, but not sure that's the right utility.

Thanks!

Comment: This is fairly broad, and there are likely many ways to resolve this but it's hard to make recommendations without more information about your current LabVIEW code.  
There is the Peak Hold function as you mentioned, there's an array min/max function, and if you are in a loop there is the option to use shit registers and do comparisons. You could also just implement a wait time if you are in a software-timed acquisition loop.  
What is driving this G code?

Comment: Would a chart perhaps be an option? Takes more space but than you get all the data easily visible and you can simply connect it to your double.

Comment: "G's" ... "IPS" ... please expand these acronyms. They may be known to you and to a few people answering the questions, but they are not helpful to Stackoverflow overall. You can phrase it with the acronym embedded so that the acronym can be used later. For example: "to output _<<full name>>_ (IPS)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier to use the Array Max & Min PtByPt.vi, this can be found in the signal processing, point by point menu. Below a VI snippit with how it works.

[image]

It will update the maximum value every 10 points. Also attached a waveform chart that shows the values.

Comment: Thanks @D.J.Klomp, I think this is what I'm looking for. I'll report back after I run it.

Comment: Thanks @D.J.Klomp - it slows my loop a bit, but I'm able to tweak and get what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jedi, just to be sure I presume you removed the wait from the loop. I just put that there to avoid my CPU going to 100% but other than that it is not functional.